# adding button inside UITextField

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, uitextfield

I'm working on a browser app for iOS and want to add a "Reader" button inside the textfield of the location bar like Mobile Safari does when it detects that the page is an article.
What's a good way to add a button on the right side of the UITextField?

Comment: What I would do is simply create a UIView that is the full width.  The add as subviews, a background image the UIButton on the right and the UITextField on the left.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to use the `rightView` property of the UITextField. Basically, there are two properties (this one and `leftView` accordingly) that allow you to place custom views/controls inside the UITextField. You can control whether those views are shown or not by means of `rightViewMode`/`leftViewMode` properties:

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton new];
// configure your button here
myTextField.rightView = myButton;
myTextField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing; // check the docs for other possible values
```

Also, there's a method called `rightViewRectForBounds:` that returns a CGRect where your custom view/control will go. you shouldn't pass your button's dimensions there directly, instead if you want to place something that is definitely bigger than the rect this method returns (seems like UITextField calls it on your behalf when you're placing a view inside it), your view will be scaled to fit this rect. It that case you might want to override it (create your category or maybe subclass of UITextField. Assuming, you go for a category your UITextField+MyButton should look something like this:

```
@interface UITextField(MyButton)
- (CGRect)rightViewRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds;
@end

@implementation UITextField(MyButton)

- (CGRect)rightViewRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    // return the CGRect that would fit your view/button. The buttons param that is passed here is the size of the view that is being added to the textField.
}

// possibly some other methods that you override

@end
```

hope this helps. And as noted in the other answer, check the docs first to see what methods are there that can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `UIButton` and position it so it overlaps the `UITextField` wherever you want it to be and in the size that makes it fit "inside" the `UITextField`.

As long as you add it to your view after you add the `UITextField`, then it will be visible above it.

Comment: I suppose, if you simply slap a button over a textfield your will not be able to see the text below the button when typing. I would go for `rightView`/`leftView` properties of the `UITextField`.

Answer (score 0):

first, implement your UIButton on the header file

.h

```
@properties (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *headerButton;
```

then at implementation file (.m)

```
@synthesize headerButton;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    UITextField *urlField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 20)];
    //your url processing code here
    //...
    //...
    //...
    [self.view addSubview:urlField];
    //declare your reader button
    readerButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 10, 25, 20)];
    [readerButton addTarget:self action:@selector(readerButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    readerButton.hidden = YES;
}
```

finally add this to ur url processing method so that the reader button only appear when the page is readable

```
   //add your condition
    if( page is pdf or readable )
    {
        readerButton.hidden = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        readerButton.hidden = YES;
    }
```

Comment: While I appreciate this is a personal opinion, I feel it's better to give the answer as some pointers to guide the asker so they can go and build their knowledge rather than giving template code like this - otherwise StackOverflow starts to become a copy/paste code repository rather than an aid to learning and development.

Comment: well, to be honest, i'm still very new to objective C too, so obviously i'm not that confident of trying to teach someone about how things supposed to works... so i just try to help by giving slice of codes that (for me) most of the time helps me discover new way to create something